# Are usernames freed when a sandbox is deleted?

Tags: sandbox, user, user-management

I know that usernames a very sticky in Salesforce, and they can't be duplicated across orgs or deleted under normal circumstances. However, what happens to a username when a sandbox it's a part of is deleted? Is the username deactivated or deleted? Is it possible to use a username from a deleted sandbox in a new sandbox?

Comment: It doesn't allow us to delete a User in Salesforce, only mark them as inactive. But if a sandbox is deleted, I guess the User would be deleted as well; then the username would be available.

Comment: your last question is amenable to an easy experiment - delete sandbox Foo with User bar; then recreate sandbox Foo. I'm sure that the sandbox will create just fine.